# remove an object from mongodb array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with removing an object in mongoose.
I have the schema

```
shareholder.model.js

const Shareholder = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    shares: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'shares' 
        }
    ],
})

mongoose.model('Shareholder', Shareholder)
```

So I'm trying to remove an object from 'shares' field

```
shareholder.service.js

// {shareholderId} id of object
// {shareId} unique id which have every object of the array

async function removeShareFromShareholder(shareholderId, shareId) {
try {
   await Shareholder.findByIdAndUpdate(shareholderId, 
                { $pull : { 'shares' : { '_id' : shareId } }},
                { safe: true })
    }
} catch (error) {
   throw new Error(`removeShareFromShareholder service error: ${error}`)
    }
}
```

But code above doesn't work

Can you give me an advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saving `ObjectId` refs, you should change the type of `shares` to `Schema.Types.ObjectId`

then since the array contains only `ids` and not a document with the `_id` property change

```
{ $pull : { 'shares' : { '_id' : shareId } }}
```

to

```
{ $pull : { shares : shareId }}
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks